# reporting services - sum expression column in tablix

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, reporting-services

I have a column in my tablix where I manually entered a long nested IF expression (its not in my dataset.)  I want to sum the whole column that contains my expression. Is there anyway to do this?

Can I give the tablix column a name, and sum that? Or do I have to take my expressions and add them to my dataset? I rather not do this, because i have 8 datasets, and I would have to add 20 expressions to each one manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your column's expression is like:

```
=iif(...)
```

- simply add a similar expression into your summary cell, with `sum(` `)` around it - like so:

```
=sum(iif(...))
```

Comment: that didn't work. it gave me an error. I don't think you can sum a column that is an expression this way in a tablix (unless you add it to the data set)

Comment: What error do you get? (I have tried this with a relatively simple expression in one of my reports and it works OK.)

Comment: @user719825 you most certainly can sum a column like this. My guess is you forgot your closing parenthesis.